# AWS Cognito Lambda triggers not created with CDK

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-cognito, aws-cdk, amazon-cognito-triggers

I can't understand why the Cognito Lambda triggers are not created. The lambdas are created, but the list of triggers in the AWS console is empty and I have to choose them manually.

```
const postConfirmationLambda = new NodejsFunction(
  this,
  'PostConfirmLambda',
  userPoolLambdasProps
);

const postAuthenticationLambda = new NodejsFunction(
  this,
  'PostAuthLambda',
  userPoolLambdasProps
);

usersTable.grantReadWriteData(postConfirmationLambda);
usersTable.grantReadWriteData(postAuthenticationLambda);

const userPool = new UserPool(this, 'UserPool', {
  removalPolicy: RemovalPolicy.DESTROY,
  lambdaTriggers: {
    postConfirmationLambda,
    postAuthenticationLambda,
  },
});
```

[Full code](https://github.com/martpet/trip-pics/blob/18fa3ca4dd86fbbcff5f2dec8e26a2451c27e7d8/backend/src/constructs/Cognito/Cognito.ts#L93)

[CloudFormation template](https://gist.github.com/martpet/d7a81eb29280b4f2065fe26912544db0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lambdaTriggers` expects a `UserPoolTriggers` interface type: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_cognito.UserPoolTriggers.html

It would look like this:

```ts
const userPool = new UserPool(this, 'UserPool', {
  removalPolicy: RemovalPolicy.DESTROY,
  lambdaTriggers: {
    postConfirmation: postConfirmationLambda,
    postAuthentication: postAuthenticationLambda,
  },
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much, sir.  I wish UserPoolTriggers warned me, if it didn't allow any string for key.